# has no segue with identifier error iOS storyboard

Tags: swift

When I read the QR code, I want to open the viewcontroller with the webview. But I get the error in the title. Even though I have made the relationship between Viewcontroller and defined it, I still get this error. I defined it in web_load, but it still looks undefined.

[image: Realtionship]

[image: identifier]

```
 func launchApp(decodedURL: String) {
           if let url = URL(string: decodedURL) {
                  if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                     // UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "web_load", sender: nil)

                  }
              }
          }) }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if segue.identifier == "web_load"{
            if let nextVC = segue.destination as? DetailsViewController {
                       nextVC.scannedCode = messageLabel.text
                   }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**webload** is segue identifier so that you can not set on viewController Storyboard ID you need to set as per given below screenshot.

**Storyboard ID** in need to set Your `ViewController` name.

[image]

Click on segue and set `identifier` as **web_load** then it can work properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set "**web_load**" as a storyboard ID not as an identifier.

Follow this step
select the segue arrow -> got to attribute inspector -> identifier(**web_load**)

like this:

[image]